# Is there a standard way to implement callbacks with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I love using `GridSearchCV` for hyper parameter tuning of machine learning models (mostly using `sklearn` here).

Is there a way to pass a function/lambda as callback that would get called after every search combination?  I would need this to add custom logging and even send events in certain scenarios.

In fact, I'm looking for a similar pattern as with Keras callbacks where every callback is being executed after every epoch.

Thanks for any insights

Comment: This is an interesting resource: https://danielhnyk.cz/adding-callback-to-a-sklearn-gridsearch/

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a way to get current parameters on my callback and found your question, hope this helps someone.

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, verbose=0, n_jobs=1)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[YourCallback()])
```